# Securing a REST proxy service in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Using WSO2ESB I am trying to add security and expose un-secured REST APIs running in WSO2DSS. 
Basically I want to store the username/password in the user store in ESB with roles and give access to APIs based on the roles. I understand client should send the authorization token in 'Authorization' http header. So how can I configure ESB to compare this token with user store and allow access to particular services only?
I am using ESB because there are some transformations to be done on the response before sending it to client. Any broad ideas would help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to use HTTP Basic authentication with the the help of http://suhan-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/wso2-dss-secure-data-service-using.html.

Please note that the latest version of WSO2ESB or DSS doesn't let you to add security directly from Management Console. Either use the Developer studio or edit the XML source directly.

Comment: Great, the previous version were having trouble to map the roles from the policy file :) We both learnt something new :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create an API in ESB to proxy your beckend REST API. Then you can write a handler to authorize API calls. See [this blog bost](http://mrmalakasilva.blogspot.com/2015/10/securing-wso2-esb-api-with-basic.html).

By the way, didn't you have a look at WSO2 API Manager? To manage your APIs, that's more suitable than ESB. If you have complex transformations, you can use ESB (fronted by APIM). If your mediation logic is not complex, you can do it inside APIM itself. See [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) for more information.

If you need more fine-grained authorization capability, you can use [entitlement mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Entitlement+Mediator) with XACML policies. See [this article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/04/access-token-based-authentication-and-authorization-using-xacml/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Bhathiya. I have done something similar to the blog you mentioned. I have only few mediators in ESB but I need to manipulate the XML messages and HTTP return codes. So guess ESB is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches.

**Direct authorization:** The simplest way is you enable the service security (on the management console), select the "username token" and then select the allowed roles. This way the client must send either:

1. use basic authentication (Authorization: Basic
2. send the WS-Security header with UsernameToken and Timestamp

Keep it simple. For most of the use cases this approach is good enough.

**Delegated authorization**: Having a 3rd party PDP (a service which says the user may access your service).

1. For fine grained authorization (e.g. only specific role in specific hours of days, etc) you can use the XACML EntitlementService (from the WSO2IS or AM) to authorize the call.
2. For authenticated users from other systems, the simplest approach is to use a Bearer token you can validate (e.g using the API Managed as already mentioned in other answers)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use HTTP Basic authentication. I had to directly edit the XML config though as mentioned in http://suhan-opensource.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/wso2-dss-secure-data-service-using.html.